# disable specific usb disk in windows service

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-services, usb

Does anyone know how can I prevent a specific USB disk/flash from installing in  a Windows Service? I don't want to disable all usb ports, I just prevent a specific usb disk from installing. I'm using windows 7.

Comment: Confiscate it and stop the user plugging it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, is possible disable **USB** disk, using *Kernel-Mode Filter Driver*.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Few years ago, I wrote project, that accept only **USB** disks with specified **VID\PID**.
Unfortunately, I can not find this project.

Comment: Man you really lit up my day! Thanks a lot! if you have more resources for the matter, please, but please send me.

Comment: My pleasure too. If I find old project sources, I send to you.